# Syntax errors at line 24 and 26. I don't know why?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

syntax error at bioinfo2.pl line 24, near ");"
syntax error at bioinfo2.pl line 26, near "}"
Execution of bioinfo2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

```
print "Enter file name......\n\n";
chomp($samplefile = <STDIN>);
open(INFILE,"$samplefile") or die "Could not open $samplefile";

@residue_name= ();
@residue_count= ();
while($newline = <INFILE>) 
{
    if ($newline =~ /^ATOM/)
    {
        chomp $newline;
        @columns = split //, $newline;  
        $res = join '', $columns[17], $columns[18], $columns[19];
        splice @columns,0;
        $flag=0
        for ($i = 0; $i<scalar(@residue_name); $i++;) 
        {
            if (@residue_name[i] == $res)
            {
                @residue_count[i] = @residue_count[i] + 1;
                $flag=1;

            }
        }
        if($flag==0)
        {
            push(@residue_name, $res);  
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i<scalar(@residue_name); $i++) 
        {   
            print (@residue_name[i], "-------", @residue_count[i], "\n");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You're missing a ; after `$flag=0`, though not sure that explains your error.  And I'm not sure you need the final ; in your for loop `for ($i = 0; $i<scalar(@residue_name); $i++;) `

Comment: Thanks. It worked. And yes the semi-colon is not required at the end of the loop.

Comment: Actually their is a logical error coming as well. The newer residues arent getting pushed into the array. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Seems to work ok for me.  Can you paste the content of a (small) sample file that isn't working?

Comment: ATOM      1  N   VAL A   1     -26.571 -16.697   2.816  1.00 35.28           N  
ATOM      2  CA  VAL A   1     -26.780 -18.181   2.665  1.00 35.30           C  
ATOM      3  C   VAL A   1     -26.952 -18.488   1.177  1.00 35.05           C

Comment: the pdb file name is 3GOU_crys.pdb

Answer (score 2):

It might be advisable to `use strict; use warnings`. That forces you to declare your variables (you can do so with `my`), and rules out many possible errors.

Here are a few things that I noticed:

1. In Perl5 v10 and later, you can use the `say` function (`use 5.010` or `use feature 'say'`). This works like `print` but adds a newline at the end.
2. Never use the two-arg form of open. This opens some security issues. Provide an explicit open mode. Also, you can use scalars as filehandles; this provides nice features like auto-closing of files.

   ```
   open my $INFILE, '<', $samplefile or die "Can't open $samplefile: $!";
   ```

   The `$!` variable contains the reason why the `open` failed.
3. If you want to retrieve a list of elements from an array, you can use a slice (multiple subscripts):

   ```
   my $res = join '', @columns[17 .. 19]; # also, range operator ".."
   ```

   Note that the sigil is now an `@`, because we take multiple elems.
4. The `splice @columns, 0` is a fancy way of saying “delete all elements from the array, and return them”. This is not neccessary (you don't read from that variable later). If you use lexical variables (declared with `my`), then each iteration of the `while` loop will receive a new variable. If you really want to remove the contents, you can `undef @columns`. This should be more efficient.
5. **Actual error:** You require a semicolon after `$flag = 0` to terminate the statement before you can begin a loop.
6. **Actual error:** A C-style for-loop contains three expressions contained in parens. Your last semicolon divides them into 4 expressions, this is an error. Simply remove it, or look at my next tip:
7. C-style loops (`for (foo; bar; baz) {}`) are painful and error-prone. If you only iterate over a range (e.g. of indices), then you can use the range operator:

   ```
   for my $i (0 .. $#residue_name) { ... }
   ```

   The `$#` sigil gives the last index of an array.
8. When subscripting arrays (accessing array elements), then you have to include the sigil of the index:

   ```
   $residue_name[$i]
   ```

   Note that the sigil of the array is `$`, because we access only one element.
9. The pattern `$var = $var + 1` can be shortened to `$var++`. This uses the increment operator.
10. The `$flag == 0` could be abbreviated to `!$flag`, as all numbers except zero are considered true.

Here is a reimplementation of the script. It takes the filename as a command line argument; this is more flexible than prompting the user.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;

my $filename = $ARGV[0]; # @ARGV holds the command line args
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

my @residue_name;
my @residue_count;

while(<$fh>) { # read into "$_" special variable
   next unless /^ATOM/; # start a new iteration if regex doesn't match

   my $number = join "", (split //)[17 .. 19]; # who needs temp variables?

   my $push_number = 1; # self-documenting variable names
   for my $i (0 .. $#residue_name) {
       if ($residue_name[$i] == $number) {
           $residue_count[$i]++;
           $push_number = 0;
       }
   }
   push @residue_name, $number if $push_number;

   # are you sure you want to print this after every input line?
   # I'd rather put this outside the loop.
   for my $i (0 .. $#residue_name) {
       say $residue_name[$i], ("-" x 7), $residue_count[$i]; # "x" repetition operator
   }
}
```

And here is an implementation that may be faster for large input files: We use hashes (lookup tables), instead of looping through arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;

my $filename = $ARGV[0]; # @ARGV holds the command line args
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

my %count_residue; # this hash maps the numbers to counts
                   # automatically guarantees that every number has one count only

while(<$fh>) { # read into "$_" special variable
   next unless /^ATOM/; # start a new iteration if regex doesn't match

   my $number = join "", (split //)[17 .. 19]; # who needs temp variables?

   if (exists $count_residue{$number}) {
     # if we already have an entry for that number, we increment:
     $count_residue{$number}++;
   } else {
     # We add the entry, and initialize to zero
     $count_residue{$number} = 0;
   }
   # The above if/else initializes new numbers (seen once) to zero.
   # If you want to count starting with one, replace the whole if/else by
   #     $count_residue{$number}++;

   # print out all registered residues in numerically ascending order.
   # If you want to sort them by their count, descending, then use
   #     sort { $count_residue{$b} <=> $count_residue{$a} } ...
   for my $num (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %count_residue) {
       say $num, ("-" x 7), $count_residue{$num};
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to chance down all the various errors. As others have said, use `use warnings;` and `use strict;`

**Rule #1**: Whenever you see *syntax error* pointing to a perfectly good line, you should always see if the line before is missing a semicolon. You forgot the semicolon after `$flag=0`.

In order to track down all the issues, I've rewritten your code into a more *modern* syntax:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

print "Enter file name......\n\n";
chomp (my $samplefile = <STDIN>);
open my $input_file, '<:crlf', $samplefile;

my @residue_name;
my @residue_count;
while ( my $newline = <$input_file> ) {
    chomp $newline;
    next if $newline !~ /^ATOM/;  #Eliminates the internal `if`
    my @columns = split //, $newline;
    my $res = join '', $columns[17], $columns[18], $columns[19];
    my $flag = 0;
    for my $i (0..$#residue_name) {
        if ( $residue_name[$i] == $res ) {
            $residue_count[$i]++;
            $flag = 1;
        }
    }
    if ( $flag == 0 ) {
        push @residue_name, $res;
    }

    for my $i (0..$#residue_name) {
        print "$residue_name[$i] -------  $residue_count[$i]\n";
    }
}
close $input_file;
```

Here's a list of changes:

- **Lines 2 & 3**: Always use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. These will help you track down about 90% of your program errors.
- **Line 4**: Use `use autodie;`. This will eliminate the need for checking whether a file opened or not.
- **Line 7 (and others)**: Using `use strict;` requires you to predeclare variables. Thus, you'll see `my` whenever a variable is first used.
- **Line 8**: Use the three parameter `open` and use *local variables* for file handles instead of globs (i.e. $file_handle vs. FILE_HANDLE). The main reasons is that local variables are easier to pass into subroutines than globs.
- **Lines 9 & 10**: No need to initialize the arrays, just declare them is enough.
- **Line 13**: Always `chomp` as soon as you read in.
- **Line 14**: Doing this eliminates an entire inner `if` statement that's embraces your entire `while` loop. Code blocks (such as `if`, `while`, and `for`) get hard to figure out when they get too long and too many embedded inside each other. Using `next` in this way allows me to eliminate the `if` block.
- **Line 17**: Here's where you missed the semicolon which gave you your first syntax error. The main thing is I eliminated the very confusing `splice` command. If you want to zero out your array, you could have simply said `@columns = ();` which is much clearer. However, since `@columns` is now in scope only in the `while` loop, I no longer have to blank it out since it will be redefined for each line of your file.
- **Line 18**: This is a much cleaner way of looping through all lines of your array. Note that `$#residue_name` gives you the last index of `$#residue_name` while scalar @resudue_name gives you the number of elements. This is a very important distinction! If I have an `@array` = `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, `$#array` will be 4, but `scalar @array` will be 5. Using the `C` style for loop can be a bit confusing when doing this. Should you use `>` or `>=`?  Using `(0..$#residue)` name is obvious and eliminate the chance of errors which included the extra semi-colon inside your C style `for` statement. Because of the chance of errors and the complexity of the syntax, The developers who created Python have decided not allow for C style for loops.
- **Line 19 (and others)**: Using `warnings` pointed out that you did `@residue_name[i]` and it had several issues. First of all, you should use `$residue_name[...]` when indexing an array, and second of all, `i` is not an integer. You meant `$i`. Thus `@residue_name[i]` becomes `$residue_name[$i]`.
- **Line 20**: If you're incrementing a variable, use `$foo++;` or `$foo += 1;` and not `$foo = $foo + 1;`. The first two make it easier to see that you're incrementing a variable and not recalculating it's value.
- **Line 29**: One of the great features of Perl is that variables can be interpolated inside quotes. You can put everything inside a single set of quotes. By the way, you should use `.` and not `,` if you do break up a `print` statement into multiple pieces. The `,` is a list operation. This means that what you print out is dependent upon the value of `$,`. The `$,` is a Perl variable that says what to print out between each item of a list when you interpolate a list into a string.

---

Please don't take this as criticism of your coding abilities. Many Perl books that teach Perl, and many course that teach Perl seem to teach Perl as it was back in the Perl 3.0 days. When I first learned Perl, it was at Perl 3.0, and much of my syntax would have looked like yours. However, Perl 5.x has been out for quite a while and contains many features that made programming easier and cleaner to read.

It took me a while to get out of Perl 3.0 habits and into Perl 4.0 and later Perl 5.0 habits. You learn by looking at what others do, and asking questions on forums like Stack Overflow.

I still can't say your code will work. I don't have your input, so I can't test it against that. However, by using this code as the basis of your program, debugging these errors should be pretty easy.

Comment: This is a truly great answer.